# Entity Framework String Size Limitation on Contains Clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So, I have this lambda expression and it works just fine

```
list = list.Where(x => x.ListaDocumentoCaixa.Any(d => d.Observacao.Contains(term.Trim())));
```

I must add that this column is a `varchar(6000)` field. So far, this has been working just fine as I mentioned, but just recently I've ran into an issue. It seems that if the term of the search occurs from position 4001 of the string and on, the query fails to return anything to me.

After some debbuging I've found this commented on the query produced by Entity Framework

```
-- p__linq__0: 'maria stela gonsa' (Type = String, Size = 4000)
```

Then after some research I found this to be Entity's common behaviour, however, I can't have this kind of limitation on the application. My question is: Is there any way to change this behaviour ? I would like very much to avoid having to write this query as plain text and run this with `ExecuteQuery` if possible.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using `First` insead of `Any`? It will increase your perfomance.

Comment: The problem I'm having is not actually performance, the problem is that Entity Framework won't search beyond position 4000 of my field. Performance-wise I'm not really having any problems at all

Comment: But this only means that `term` cannot be longer than 4000. I can search in an `nvarchar(max)` field beyond 4000 characters and the query is translated as `LIKE`. Which database (provider + version) are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you follow the following article, assuming you are using SQL server, about how to create a full text search index, and use it in Entity Framework with C#.

Running LIKE statements (which is what Contains() maps to) is HIGHLY inefficient on large varchar fields.

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/298/implementing-sql-server-full-text-search-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-with-entity-framework

EDIT:  The summary of the link is:

1.) Create a full text index on the field using SQL server's wizard.  That full text field will allow CONTAINS and FREETEXT searches on the whole field, and be much more efficient.

2.) Write a stored procedure that joins the table in question to results from the free text index.

3.) Make an Entity Framework class to represent results from that stored procedure, and use EF to call in and return a list of those results.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17391822)

Comment: Done.  Good suggestion.

Comment: This could be handy in the future, but what I really needed is a way to increase this size cap of 4000 to string parameters. Also, I did a lot of digging and found out that using `Contains` actually translates to `CHARINDEX`. The performance isn't my problem here, only the size cap

Comment: Perhaps, but full text indexes do search the whole field without a cap.

Comment: If I query the same thing in SSMS I get the result I want. The major problem here is EF, since it is the one limiting my search to 4000 chars. I figured that there may be some way to change this behaviour, but I can't find it anywhere